# I've got my work cut out for me. Origin, meaning, negation by sarcasm?

Tags: expressions, idioms, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrase-origin

The phrase "I've got my work cut out for me" I have until now mistaken to mean: "The work that I have to do is largely completed (due to efforts by others beforehand), and only need to do a little bit more to finish". But I find that it actually means "The work I have to do is going to be difficult, and will take tremendous time and effort to complete".

Is there any evidence that supports the former meaning<strike>, other than being used in a sarcastic context? Or, can the former meaning be true only if used in sarcasm</strike>?

Also, I am curious about the origin of this phrase, and would love to know about its first appearance.

Comment: The expression can be found at [idioms.thefreedictionary.com](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+work+cut+out) and the origin (including the sense you query) at [WorldWideWords](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-wor1.htm).

Comment: Of course, 'a little bit more [on each one] to finish' **becomes** 'The work I have to do is going to be difficult, and will take tremendous time and effort to complete' if enough cut-outs have been prepared. And the 'little bit' was probably 90% of the task.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ah, I seem to have taken the two meanings as being opposite, but as you point out, it is more nuanced than that. By the use of this idiom, it is apparent that there is work to do, but the quantity and difficulty of the work may differ according to the view of the speaker. It seems to me that the idiom augments the quantity and difficulty of the work, and so most listeners would deem that the speaker was faced with a lot of work to do if they said they'd "had their work cut out" for them.

Comment: I think you’re confusing “cut out for you” with “cut down for you”   *to cut down* is to reduce.

Answer (score 2):

> Also, I am curious about the origin of this phrase, and would love to
>   know about its first appearance.

**To have (one's) work cut out for one** is from 1610s; to have it prepared and prescribed, hence, **to have all one can handle**. Old English weorc (n), wircan, wyrcan (vb); related to Old High German wurchen, German wirken, Old Norse yrkja, Gothic waurkjan]  [etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/word/work)

More etymology here: [worldwidewords](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-wor1.htm)

> Is there any evidence that supports the former meaning, other than
>   being used in a sarcastic context? Or, can the former meaning be true
>   only if used in sarcasm?

My sense is no to both of your questions.